# how to override !important in the css

Tags: css

I would like to change the css but I can't override the defaults. 
My page code is `

```
<h1 class="page_title">Today's Top Ten Videos</h1>              
<div id="main_inner">
<div class="top-layout"><div class="top-layout-row">
<div class="top-layout-cell"><h4 class="top-video-title">
 <a href="http://xxx">Title</a></h4>
```

The following css is across the site and I can't change it. :

```
#main_inner h4, #main_inner h4 a{
 letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 155%;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  background-color: #f5f3f3 !important;
  color: #006c9f !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
}
#main h4:before, footer .widgettitle:before, h1.page_title:before, #sidebar h4.widgettitle:before, .about_author_title:before, #reply-title:before, #comments_title:before {
  content: "|||";
}
```

I'm trying to change the css to 
`h4.top-video-title{background-color:none !important;}
h4.top-video-title ::before{  content: "";}`

but it isn't working. How do I change the css?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS Specificity to do the override. 
Use more selectors than the ones used in the legacy code you found on the site.

For instance:

```
#main_inner h4, #main_inner h4 a{
 letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 155%;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  background-color: #f5f3f3 !important;
  color: #006c9f !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
}
#main h4:before, footer .widgettitle:before, h1.page_title:before, #sidebar h4.widgettitle:before, .about_author_title:before, #reply-title:before, #comments_title:before {
  content: "|||";
}
```

If you want to override:

```
#main_inner h4
```

you need to use more selectors or a higher selector since they used an id.

Try

```
#main_inner h4.top-video-title{
   background-color:none !important;
}
```

I wrote a post about this a while ago: http://blog4coders.com/css-specificity/

Comment: That's the correct answer, it is all about specificity!

Comment: Yes dippas, indeed :)

Comment: It isn't changing the actual color behind the text letters, only the background around the text.

Comment: If it doesn't change that it means either the specificity it's still not higher or there is another inner div with background color set. Try background:transparent; as well to see what happens.

Comment: To increase specificity just add more parent div classes to the selector for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the CSS priority, as the others have nested selectors. Try to use the same selectors as the existing ones, but adding `body` before:

`body #main_inner h4, body #main_inner h4 a`

and `!important` to the rule too, so you can increase the selector priority.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of none, use Transparent !important

```
h4.top-video-title { 
 background-color: Transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't override the #main_inner

Comment: Yes, but there is no 'none' as color value. Only transparent or valid color value/name.